# On the selection coefficient

Tags: genetics, evolution, population-genetics, theoretical-biology

I'm reading  Williams' [Adaptation and Natural Selection:
A Critique of Some Current Evolutionary Thought](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/558.html).

In this book the author talks about [selection coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_coefficient) which, if I understand it correctly, can be calculated as finiteness arithmetic means (for each allele).

My question is: should this calculation be made assuming a ceteris paribus condition?

Answer (score 2):

**Definition of selection coefficient**

A selection coefficient is a difference in fitness between two genotypes (or haplotypes). Let the two genotypes be `A` and `B`. Let's use relative fitness and say that the fitness of `A` is $w_A = 1$ and the fitness of `B` is $w_B = 1 - s$, where $s$ is the selection coefficient. As a consequence $w_A - w_B = s$.

The question of long-term fitness is unrelated to the definition of selection coefficient, as the selection coefficient is defined as a difference in fitness. A question of importance is "What measure of fitness should one use for a population where selective pressures are changing over time and/or space".

**What measure of fitness should one use for a population where selective pressures are changing over time and/or space**

Roughly speaking, if changes in fitness are over space, then you should use arithmetic mean fitness and if changes in fitness are over time, then you should use the geometric mean fitness but it is not quite that easy.

The real interest is whether fitnesses are correlated among generations. In other words, do individuals within a generation tend to have a more similar fitness values than the individuals of another generation? When variation in fitness is spatial than one should not expect such correlation. When variation is temporal one should expect such correlation.

Hoping you can read a code in R, the easiest is probably to read some code that make a simulation and look at the output. So here is a code that performs simulations. The key difference between simulations with spatial and temporal variation is the line that gets fitness value (`runif`).

```
set.seed(43)

temporalVariation = function(N, lowestFitness, highestFitness, nbgenerations)
{
    Ns = numeric(nbgenerations)
    Ns[1] = N
    for (generation in 2:nbgenerations)
    {
        fitnessPerIndThisGeneration = runif(1,lowestFitness, highestFitness) # All individuals have the same fitness in a specific generation   
        N = N * fitnessPerIndThisGeneration
        Ns[generation] = N
    }
    return (Ns)
}


spatialVariation  = function(N, lowestFitness, highestFitness, nbgenerations)
{
    Ns = numeric(nbgenerations)
    Ns[1] = N
    for (generation in 2:nbgenerations)
    {
        FitnessOfEachIndividual = runif(N, lowestFitness, highestFitness) # Individuals differ in fitness within a generation
        N = sum(FitnessOfEachIndividual)
        Ns[generation] = N      
    }
    return (Ns)
}


N = 1000
lowestFitness = 0.95
highestFitness = 1.08
nbgenerations = 200

spatialNs = spatialVariation(N, lowestFitness, highestFitness, nbgenerations)
temporalNs = temporalVariation(N, lowestFitness, highestFitness, nbgenerations)

plot(y= spatialNs, x=1:nbgenerations, col='blue', xlab = 'generation', ylab = 'N')
points(y= temporalNs, x=1:nbgenerations, col='red')
```

[image]

In blue is the simulation with spatial variation. In red is the simulation with temporal variation. You will note that the geometric mean is always equal or lower than the arithmetic mean.

Whether the arithmetic or geometric mean fitness matters most will affect the reproductive system that will be most successful. In this regard, you should read [Ripa et al. 2009](http://rspb.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/277/1685/1153) about bet-hedging

Comment: "Roughly speaking, if changes in fitness are over space, then you should use arithmetic mean fitness and if changes in fitness are over time, then you should use the geometric mean fitness but it is not quite that easy."  Remi, would you explain/elaborate on this?

Comment: @sterid See edit. I am not 100% sure how to explain it, so I decided to write and show results of a simulation. Hopefully that will make sense when reading the code.

Comment: I appreciate your writing the code, but I don't know the R language.  I have a couple questions if you feel like indulging:

Comment: Never mind.  I understand the program.  Will study it & probably have questions.  Thank you.

Comment: OK I see why that result was obtained.  Would you please explain the relevance of "You will note that the geometric mean is always equal or lower than the arithmetic mean." ?

Comment: It means that environmental variance on fitness causes a greater decrease in long term fitness if this variance is temporal rather than spatial. This whole subject is very interesting especially in the bet-hedging literature. The first one to point out to this effect was Richard Levin. His book [evolution in changing environment](https://www.amazon.ca/Evolution-Changing-Environments-Theoretical-Explorations/dp/0691080623/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1489900796&sr=8-1&keywords=Evolution+in+Changing+Environments) is all focused on that (IMO it is old and not very pleasant to read though).

Comment: But isn't it true that if you consider the effects of selection, you must have spatial variance in order to have temporal variance and vice versa (as long as heritability is high)?